# What is the simplest way of getting exchange messages into SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, exchange-server

SQL Server has dbmail for sending mails but how to get emails easily inside database?

Comment: Are talking about doing this 1) from a program, e.g. a C# app or something like that, or do you mean 2) to do this from your Exchange server using some tools etc.??

Comment: At best directly from SQL server. Currently there is outlook running on client PC with onreceive macro but it is not reliable.

Comment: I am looking into CLR procedures...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973053/c-exchange-email-client here is good tip - put all emails to folder using admin rule - sql job could then pick it up from there to process but is there an API to get email as object...

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about Exchange 2007/2010, you should look into SyncFolderItems:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.syncfolderitems(v=exchg.80).aspx

EWS Managed API - Download: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=13480

EWS Managed API - SDK: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx