# Is it possible to read an email reply in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have triggered mail using database `mail(sp_db_sendmail)`. I replied to that triggered mail.

Is it possible to get that reply message in SQL Server 2012?

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here. Are you asking if you can use sql as a mail client? You could save a copy of the email in sql server.

Comment: as of now we see only sent mail in sql server.Whether we can see the reply mail in sql server

Comment: Well sql server is NOT an email client. If you have an actual mailbox for this you could use exchange/outlook to retrieve these emails.

Answer (score 2):

No ..you can't get that using `sp_send_email`..you have to query exchange using outlook account used for sending emails

sample code taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368380/reading-outlook-mail-with-c-sharp):

```
inboxFolder = nameSpace.Folders["my-account@myserver.com"].Folders["Unsent mails"];

foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem in inboxFolder.Items)
{
    if (mailItem.UnRead) // I only process the mail if unread
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Accounts: {0}", mailItem.Body);
    }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur immediate response.

Comment: you are replying to a message sent ,by sp_send_dbmail,dbmail sends message through an account and it doesnt read messages it got

Comment: i got it.my requirement is employee apply the leave and mail goes to HR.HR approved the leave via mail only. how i handle this one.kindly suggest to me.

Comment: with out knowing much details,i could say have a table with leave details,now you can easily populate details against employeeids