# Reading Multiple Outlook Email for multiple IDs in C#

Tags: c#, email, outlook, office-interop

Referring to the answer mentioned in the post:
[Reading Outlook Mail with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368380/reading-outlook-mail-with-c-sharp)

This code works well for a single account, but the issue with the current code is that it reads the email of the default id which was set as the first one in the outlook app.

For example, if "abcxyz@outlook.com" is set as the first account and "decxyz@outlook.com" is set as the second one, then it reads the inbox of only the first id, i.e.,  "abcxyz@outlook.com". I tried doing some modifications in the code but it did not work. Below is my code:

```
  public static void OutLookMailStart(string EmailID, string password)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PostItem item = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder subFolder = null;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;
        try
        {
            app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

            ns.Logon(EmailID, password, false, true);
            inboxFolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);

            foreach (Object mail in inboxFolder.Items)
            {
                if ((mail as MailItem) != null && (mail as MailItem).UnRead == true)
                {
                    // Email Subject 
                    string Subject = (mail as MailItem).Subject.ToString();
                    if (Subject.Contains(FileDomain))
                    {
                        // Email Body
                        var ReplyText = ExtractReply(((mail as MailItem).Body.ToString()), FromTrimName);
                    }
                    // (mail as MailItem).UnRead = false;
                    (mail as MailItem).Save();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            ns.Logoff();
            inboxFolder = null;
            subFolder = null;
            mailItem = null;
            app = null;
        }}
```

Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you by any chance able to use Exchange Web Services instead of Outlook interop?

Comment: could you give or explain, what is the "FileDomain" in above your code? and also from where you calling this "OutLookMailStart" methode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public static void OutLookMailStart(string EmailID, string password)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.PostItem item = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder inboxFolder = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder subFolder = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = null;


            try
            {
                app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
                ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

                ns.Logon(EmailID, password, true, true);

                inboxFolder = ns.Folders[EmailID].Folders[2];

                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItemm in inboxFolder.Items)
                {
                    if (mailItemm.UnRead) // I only process the mail if unread
                    {
                        // Email Subject 
                        Console.WriteLine("Subject : {0}", mailItemm.Subject);
                        string Subject = mailItemm.Subject;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Subject) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Subject))
                        {
                            if (Subject.Contains(FileDomain))
                            {


                                var SenderName = mailItemm.Sender.Name;
                                //Email Body
                                Console.WriteLine("Accounts: {0}", mailItemm.Body);




                                // Read All Attachements  
                                var attachments = (mailItemm as MailItem).Attachments;
                                if (attachments != null && attachments.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    for (int i = 1; i <= attachments.Count; i++)
                                    {
                                        attachments[i].SaveAsFile(tempFolderPath + (mailItemm as MailItem).Attachments[i].FileName);


                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                ns.Logoff();
                inboxFolder = null;
                subFolder = null;
                mailItem = null;
                app = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: inboxFolder = ns.Folders[EmailID].Folders[2];  2 means Index Folder

Comment: could you give or explain, what is the "FileDomain" in above your code? and also from where you calling this "OutLookMailStart" methode?

Answer (score 0):

Using ExchangeService service

```
public static void Cloud_OutLookMailStart(string EmailID, string password, string StoreFilePath)
{
    try
    {
        LogHelper.LogMessage("<----- Cloud_OutLookMailStart Start ----->");

        DistributionReplyEntity ObjDistributionReplyEntity = new DistributionReplyEntity();
        ObjDistributionReplyEntity.OutLookEmailID = EmailID;
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
        service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(EmailID, password);
        service.TraceEnabled = true;
        service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
        //service.Url = new Uri("https://IP/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
        service.AutodiscoverUrl(EmailID, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

        Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder inbox = Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Folder.Bind(service, WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);

        var items = service.FindItems(
        //Find Mails from Inbox of the given Mailbox
        new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox(EmailID)),
        //Filter criterion
        //  new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter[] {
        //  new SearchFilter.ContainsSubstring(ItemSchema.Subject, ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidEmailIdentifier"].ToString()),
        new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false),
        //  }),

        //View Size as 15


        new ItemView(50));

        Console.WriteLine("Email {0}, unread Total Count{1}", EmailID, items.Count());


        foreach (Item item in items)
        {
            EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(service, new ItemId(item.Id.UniqueId.ToString()));

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email.Subject) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email.Subject))
            {
                var subject = email.Subject.ToString();
                String[] arr = subject.Split(' ');

                String firstWord = arr[0];
                if (firstWord != "Undeliverable:")
                {
                    //PROCESS EMAIL MESSAGE 
                    Console.WriteLine("Subject :{0}", email.Subject);
                    // TO
                    if (email.ToRecipients.Count > 0)
                    {

                        var propertySet = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.UniqueBody);
                        EmailMessage email2 = EmailMessage.Bind(service, email.Id, propertySet);
                        EmailMessage str = (EmailMessage)email2;
                        string str1 = str.UniqueBody.Text.ToString();
                        var EmailBody = ExtractReply(str1, "");
                        // string ReceiverEmail = email.ReceivedBy != null?email.ReceivedBy.Address:"" ;
                        // Email Body 

                        // var subjectEmail = ExtractReply(email.Body.ToString(), email.ReceivedBy.Address);

                        Console.WriteLine("Body {0}", EmailBody.ToString()); // Body
                        ObjDistributionReplyEntity.EmailBody = EmailBody;

                        string maltipleTo = string.Empty;
                        foreach (var toemailid in email.ToRecipients)
                        {
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(maltipleTo))
                            {
                                maltipleTo = toemailid.Address.ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                maltipleTo += ";" + toemailid.Address.ToString();
                            }
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("TO {0}", maltipleTo.ToString()); // TO
                        ObjDistributionReplyEntity.ReplyTO = maltipleTo.ToString();
                    }
                    // CC
                    if (email.CcRecipients.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string maltipleCC = string.Empty;
                        foreach (var ccemailid in email.CcRecipients)
                        {

                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(maltipleCC))
                            {
                                maltipleCC = ccemailid.Address.ToString();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                maltipleCC += ";" + ccemailid.Address.ToString();
                            }
                        }

                        Console.WriteLine("CC {0}", maltipleCC.ToString());
                        ObjDistributionReplyEntity.ReplyCC = maltipleCC.ToString();
                    }
                    // Form
                    if (email.Sender.Address != "")
                    {
                        ObjDistributionReplyEntity.ReplyForm = email.Sender.Address;
                    }

                    Console.WriteLine("Subject {0}", email.Subject.ToString()); // Subject
                    ObjDistributionReplyEntity.Subject = email.Subject.ToString();


                    ObjDistributionReplyEntity.TransactionsID = 0;
                    ObjDistributionReplyEntity.IsProjectRelated = 0;
                    string Subject = email.Subject;




                    ObjDistributionReplyEntity.ReceivedTime = email.DateTimeReceived;

                    var getSharePointFileUrl = GetAttachmentsFromEmail(service, item.Id, StoreFilePath, ObjDistributionReplyEntity.TransactionsID);


                    email.IsRead = true;
                    email.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite);
                }
            }
        }

        LogHelper.LogMessage("<----- Cloud_OutLookMailStart Start ----->");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogHelper.LogError("OutLookMailStart -> Cloud_OutLookMailStart Exception");
        LogHelper.LogError("Exception Message :" + ex.Message);
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            LogHelper.LogError("Exception InnerException :" + ex.InnerException);
        }
        LogHelper.LogError("Exception StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace);
        LogHelper.LogError("OutLookMailStart -> Cloud_OutLookMailStart Exception");
    }
}
```

public static string GetAttachmentsFromEmail(ExchangeService service, ItemId itemId, string StoreFilePath, Int64 TransactionsID)
    {

```
    try
    {
        LogHelper.LogMessage("<----- GetAttachmentsFromEmail Start ----->");





        // Bind to an existing message item and retrieve the attachments collection.
        // This method results in an GetItem call to EWS.
        EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, itemId, new PropertySet(ItemSchema.Attachments));
        List<ResponseMessage> ObjResponseMessage = new List<ResponseMessage>();
        // Iterate through the attachments collection and load each attachment.
        foreach (Attachment attachment in message.Attachments)
        {
            if (attachment is FileAttachment)
            {
                FileAttachment fileAttachment = attachment as FileAttachment;

                // Load the attachment into a file.
                // This call results in a GetAttachment call to EWS.

                fileAttachment.Load(StoreFilePath + fileAttachment.Name);


                string FileName = fileAttachment.Name;





                LogHelper.LogMessage("OutLookMailStart In attachments File Name :" + FileName );


                Console.WriteLine("File attachment name: " + fileAttachment.Name);
            }
            else // Attachment is an item attachment.
            {
                ItemAttachment itemAttachment = attachment as ItemAttachment;

                // Load attachment into memory and write out the subject.
                // This does not save the file like it does with a file attachment.
                // This call results in a GetAttachment call to EWS.
                itemAttachment.Load();

                Console.WriteLine("Item attachment name: " + itemAttachment.Name);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogHelper.LogError("OutLookMailStart -> GetAttachmentsFromEmail Exception");
        LogHelper.LogError("Exception Message :" + ex.Message);
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
        {
            LogHelper.LogError("Exception InnerException :" + ex.InnerException);
        }
        LogHelper.LogError("Exception StackTrace :" + ex.StackTrace);
        LogHelper.LogError("OutLookMailStart -> GetAttachmentsFromEmail Exception"); ;
    }
    LogHelper.LogMessage("<----- GetAttachmentsFromEmail End ----->");


}
```

Comment: This would be *far* better with an explanation rather than a huge code dump.